# WinInet how to use sock proxy

Tags: c++, proxy, wininet

I'd like to use WinInet to access a web page but with a sock4/sock5 proxy.

Here is what I've tried:

```cpp
HINTERNET hOpen = InternetOpenA(helper.USER_AGENT, INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY, ("SOCKS5=200.100.5.1:702", NULL, 0);
```

This doesn't seem to work, I'm supplying an invalid sock proxy so that when it does the web page connection it should not go through, but in my tests it's going through meaning the sock proxy is not being used but rather my actual plain internet.

I've even made a helper function to set the proxy in `InternetSetOption()` as well:

```cpp
bool changeProxy(const char* socket) {
    char strProxyList[MAX_PATH];
    bool success = false;

    memset(strProxyList, 0, MAX_PATH);

    lstrcpyA(strProxyList, "SOCKS5=");

    INTERNET_PROXY_INFO proxy;

    proxy.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
    proxy.lpszProxy = (LPCTSTR)strProxyList;
    proxy.lpszProxyBypass = NULL;

    if (TRUE == InternetSetOptionA(hOpen, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, &proxy, sizeof(INTERNET_PROXY_INFO)))
    {
        printf("Socket set to %s\n", socket);
        success = true;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed to set socket to %s\n", socket);
    }

    InternetSetOptionA(NULL, INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_SETTINGS_CHANGED, NULL, 0);
    return success;
}
```

In which I've tried calling this function after the `InternetOpenA()` and right before the `InternetConnectA()` function, but for whatever reason it doesn't use the proxy but rather my plain internet.

Here is my connection code snippet:

```cpp
hConnect = InternetConnectA(hOpen, host, INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTPS_PORT, NULL, NULL, 3, 0, 0);
hRequest = HttpOpenRequestA(hConnect, "POST", uri, NULL, CHECKER_URL, NULL, INTERNET_FLAG_SECURE, 0);
```

**UPDATE:**

Using this code, I was able to get the proxy set.

But, for some reason, it only allows me to set the proxy one time and never again while the process is running:

```cpp
HINTERNET hOpen = InternetOpenA(helper.USER_AGENT, 0, NULL, NULL, 0);
INTERNET_PROXY_INFO proxy = { 0 };

proxy.dwAccessType = INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY;
proxy.lpszProxy = (LPCTSTR)socket;
proxy.lpszProxyBypass = NULL;
    
if (UrlMkSetSessionOption(INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY, &proxy, sizeof(proxy), 0) != 0)
{
    success = false;
}
UrlMkSetSessionOption(INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY_SETTINGS_CHANGED, NULL, 0, 0);
```

I want to change the proxy mid-program after doing this once, but using the same code the proxy change a 2nd time doesn't take affect.

I've even tried closing the handle and re-instantiating it, but no luck.

When trying to use:

```cpp
InternetSetOptionA(hOpen, INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION, &proxy, sizeof(INTERNET_PROXY_INFO)))
```

I get a return value of false, so it's not setting that way, for some reason. But using `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY` sets it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a SOCKS proxy, try using `CERN_PROXY_INTERNET_ACCESS` instead of `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY`. And change `SOCKS5=` to `SOCKS=`.

Also, your `changeProxy()` function has several logic bugs. Your typecast from `char[]` to `LPCTSTR` is suspicious and wrong, and you are not actually providing any proxy server in the list anyway.

Comment: Thank you for the tips.  is the changeProxy() function even needed if the CERN_PROXY change inside the InternetOpenA() function fixes the proxy setting issue?

Comment: @mocode9 I'm not sure, but you shouldn't be using `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY` to begin with, use `INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION` instead. See [How to programmatically query and set proxy settings under Internet Explorer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/226473).

Comment: I got it working but it seems to change the proxy settings only once. Id like to be able to change them again later in my program in case the proxy is no longer alive. But after the first change subsequent ones don't seem to have any effect.  Any ideas?

Comment: @mocode9: which option are you using to set it?  `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY` applies to the static global settings, whereas `INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION` has to be applied to every `HINTERNET` handle you open. Please [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/41540311/edit) to show your latest code.

Comment: Currently using INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY.  So by static global settings you mean even if I close the handle and instantiate a new one that proxy settings will still exist and cannot be overridden?

Comment: Added my new code still no luck changing it a 2nd time, only first change works.

Comment: Stop using `INTERNET_OPTION_PROXY`, use `INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION` instead. MS says so. You should be setting the proxy each time you create a new URL request. This also means stop using `UrlMkSetSessionOption()` since it "allows only global options to be set".

Comment: What function would I use that accepts a proxy to make the http request?  I'm using HttpOpenRequestA() right now and don't see any parameters that would take a proxy specifier.

Comment: If I do INTERNET_OPTION_PER_CONNECTION_OPTION and pass in the  INTERNET_OPTION_REFRESH flag as well it says it will retrieve the proxy information from the registry.  Wouldn't this defeat the whole purpose?

Comment: <sigh> `HttpOpenRequest()` takes a handle from `InternetConnect()` as input, which takes a handle from `InternetOpen()` as input, which accepts a proxy server as input.

Comment: I'd like to be able to use the same handle just with different proxy settings.  But for some reason that's not possible.  Ended up having to fork everytime I wanted a different proxy. Super inefficient.  Not a fan of WinInet

Comment: You can't reuse WinInet handles for different connections, and switching proxies requires establishing new connections. This is not really a WinInet limitation. Even if you dropped down to the TCP layer and implemented SOCKS and HTTP(S) manually, you still couldn't do it. You can switch proxies between HTTP requests, but not over the same connection, you would have to drop the existing connection first.

Comment: I closed the handle returned from Internet open and reinstantiated a new one before switching the proxies but it doesn't seem to take affect.

Comment: Using  `CERN_PROXY_INTERNET_ACCESS` instead of `INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY` is quite pointles, at it is defined like this: `#define CERN_PROXY_INTERNET_ACCESS  INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY` in WinInet.h