# InternetOpenUrl() returning the error code 12007 (ERROR_INTERNET_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED/ERROR_WINHTTP_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)

Tags: c++, winapi, tor, wininet

I am attempting to fetch the HTML source behind an onion site via the `WinINet` API but the `InternetOpenUrl()` returns the error code of 12007 which suggests that there is an issue regrading the resolution of the web address. The unusual part of this problem is that the error is not reproducible  when a non-onion site is used for the web link, which clearly means that there is no issue in the part concerning the proxy configurations.

```
PCWSTR userAgent = L"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0"; // Tor browser 9.5
PCWSTR torProxyServer = L"SOCKS=127.0.0.1:9150";
PCWSTR onionAddr = L"https://3g2upl4pq6kufc4m.onion/"; //
//PCWSTR onionAddr = L"http://checkip.dyndns.org/"; // Works fine!
HINTERNET iConnSock = nullptr;
HINTERNET addrSock = nullptr;
DWORD errCode;
LPWSTR errMsg;
DWORD errMsgLen;
iConnSock = InternetOpen(userAgent, 
        INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_PROXY,
        //CERN_PROXY_INTERNET_ACCESS, // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540311/wininet-how-to-use-sock-proxy
        torProxyServer, 
        nullptr, 
        0);
if (nullptr == iConnSock) {
   errCode = GetLastError(); 
   std::cout << "Error initializing the WININET API\nError code: " << errCode << "\n";
   return 0;
}
addrSock = InternetOpenUrl(iConnSock, 
        onionAddr, 
        nullptr, 
        -1L, 
        INTERNET_FLAG_EXISTING_CONNECT 
            | INTERNET_FLAG_HYPERLINK 
            | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_CN_INVALID 
            | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_CERT_DATE_INVALID
            | INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE
            | INTERNET_FLAG_KEEP_CONNECTION
            | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTP 
            | INTERNET_FLAG_IGNORE_REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS 
            | INTERNET_FLAG_RELOAD 
            | INTERNET_FLAG_RESYNCHRONIZE, 
        0);
if (nullptr == addrSock) {
   errCode = GetLastError();
   std::cout << "Error opening the URL\n";
   if (ERROR_INTERNET_EXTENDED_ERROR == errCode) {
      errMsgLen = 0;
      errMsg = nullptr;
      if (ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER == InternetGetLastResponseInfo(&errCode, errMsg, &errMsgLen)) {
         errMsg = new WCHAR[errMsgLen];
         if (TRUE == InternetGetLastResponseInfo(&errCode, errMsg, &errMsgLen))
            std::wcout << "Error code: " << errCode << "\nError message: " << errMsg << "\n";
         else
            std::cout << "Error fetching the cause of error!\n";
         delete[] errMsg;
      }
      else {
         std::wcout << "Error fetching the cause of error!\n";
      }
   }
   else {
      std::cout << "Error code: " << errCode << "\n";
   }
   InternetCloseHandle(iConnSock);
   return 0;
}
InternetCloseHandle(addrSock);
InternetCloseHandle(iConnSock);
```

The above code outputs:

```
Error opening the URL
Error code: 12007
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe a security issue. You can trace Wininet calls using ETW: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/05/09/announcing-traceprocessor-preview-0-1-0/

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried running the code with admin privileges but the issue still persists.

Comment: You are not doing error handling on `InternetOpen()` before calling `InternetOpenUrl()`. You are also calling `GetLastError()` too late, the `cout` printing *can* potentially wipe out the error code before you retrieve it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I merely omitted the error handling portion regarding the ```InternetOpen()``` function only in the question to put emphasis on the actual issue at hand as the aforementioned function completes without any errors. I have modified the code to call ```GetLastError()``` right after the null pointer check part but it yields the same outcome.

Comment: I meant more certificate chain security. But traces should tell you more